# Replace next line using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have a huge file (it is a translation file for WordPress LocoTranslate plugin), and I need to translate what is in the `msgstr` quotes from what is in the `msgid` quotes. For instance:

```
#: ../../app/Models/SettingsAPI.php:105, 
#: ../../app/Controllers/Settings/AdminSettings.php:354
msgid "Your settings have been saved."
msgstr "Tus opciones fueron guardadas."

#: ../../app/Models/SettingsAPI.php:695, 
#: ../../app/Controllers/Admin/Meta/AddTermMetaField.php:357, 
#: ../../app/Controllers/Admin/Meta/AddTermMetaField.php:469
msgid "Add Image"
msgstr "Agregar Imagen"
```

I have tried using Google Sheets and the Google Translate API, but it is completely inaccurate, so I decided to go small at first and just transpose the string like:

```
#: ../../app/Models/SettingsAPI.php:105, 
#: ../../app/Controllers/Settings/AdminSettings.php:354
msgid "Your settings have been saved."
msgstr "Your settings have been saved."
```

I thought some text editor like Notepad++ could do this magic with a regular expression `msgid \"(.*)\"`, but I wouldn't know how to replace the next line (`msgstr.*`) entirely.

I am pretty sure this question had to be made before actually making [the tool](https://github.com/maramal/regsearch-ts) to help me translate the file, but I was not that good with Notepad++ capabilities. Also, the tool does not work as expected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can not replace something with regex, that you did not match in the first place. Instead of trying to match that first line and then replacing the "next", you need to match both lines in one go - and then replace that whole match with the original first line plus the modified second line.

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace the `msgstr` double quoted content to that that of `msgid`? For this you can [replace `^msgid\s+"([^"]+)"\Rmsgstr\s+"\K[^"]+` to `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/tcST6e/1) e.g. with Notepad++ (PCRE). Or use two [capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html): E.g. [replace `^(msgid\s+"([^"]+)"\r?\nmsgstr\s+")[^"]+` with `$1$2`](https://regex101.com/r/rE9Wn6/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++ do this:

- Find what: `^(msgid ")(.*)("\s+msgstr ").*(")`
- Replace with: `$1$2$3$2$4`
- check `(o)` Regular expression, uncheck `[_]` , matches newline

The regex takes into account escaped `"` in the strings

Answer (score 0):

```
(msgid .*)               to keep
\n                       newline
.*                       to replace
```

`.replace(/(msgid .*)\n.*/g, '$1')`